# Mask technique to mask different objects are not showing proper output

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to work out a technique to mask different objects in different scenarios. But, it's not performing as I was expecting from it. I was working with 10 labels. It's performing well in some cases and worst in some cases. It couldn't mask all 10 labels correctly. I couldn't sort out how could I make it work as I was expecting.

I have the following code that does the above task-

```
def apply_mask_in_image(img2, result):
    # apply the mask in result
    return cv2.bitwise_and(img2, result)


def get_mask(thresh, img2):
    # apply morphology open then close
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    blob = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9, 9))
    blob = cv2.morphologyEx(blob, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # invert blob
    blob = (255 - blob)
    # Get contours
    cnts = cv2.findContours(blob, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    big_contour = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # test blob size
    blob_area_thresh = 1000
    blob_area = cv2.contourArea(big_contour)
    if blob_area < blob_area_thresh:
        print("Blob Is Too Small")
    # draw contour mask
    result = np.zeros(img2.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.fillPoly(result, pts=[big_contour], color=(255, 255, 255))
    return result


def get_threshold(img):
    img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 120, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    img = np.array(255 * (img / 255) ** 1.5, dtype='uint8')
    # convert img to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # do adaptive threshold on gray image
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

    return thresh


thresh = get_threshold(image)
result = apply_mask_in_image(get_mask(thresh, image), image)
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

For 10 labels, if I take one image for each label the results are like the following-
label1: diseased plants stem stype1

label2: diseased plants stem stype2

label3: diseased plants leaf ltype1

label4: Healthy plants leaf

label5: Healthy plants stem

label6: diseased plants leaf ltype2

label7: diseased plants leaf ltype3

label8: diseased plants stem stype3

label9: diseased plants stem stype4

label10: diseased plants leaf ltype5

But in each image, there are other plants in the image also but masking the focused image.

label1 mask

[image: image description]

label2 mask

[image: image description]

label3 mask

[image: image description]

label4 mask

[image: image description]

label5 mask

[image: image description]

label6 mask

[image: image description]

label7 mask

[image: image description]

label8 mask

[image: image description]

label9 mask

[image: image description]

label10 mask

[image: image description]